# Chuck for a Dremel

Tags: chuck

Having purchased (and loving) a Dremel 4000, I decided a chuck for different sizes of small drill bits would be a good addition. Bought a couple, but neither appears to have the same thread as the Dremel. Any ideas - on what thread it actually possesses? Or where I could obtain a suitable chuck?

Answer (score 2):

I had an older brand Weller 'Dremel' tool missing collets.  I got these from Wish.com:

Hot 11PCS/Set Brass Drill Chucks Collet Bits 0.5-3.2mm 4.8mm Shank Screw Nut Replacement for Dremel Rotary Tool
11pcs/set

They fit perfect (although shipping took a long time).

[image]

Comment: Thanks - just ordered! I'll wait (and wait, and wait) and see...